# Python:Tkinter multiple widgets are acting as one

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i have this problem: Multiple Tkinter widgets created with a loop are acting as one single widget. In example - if i create 4 Scale elements, they are all acting as one - if i pick one slider - all sliders get selected. The same is With OptionMenu, though there are no problems with buttons.

Sample code:

```
def frame4Gui( self ):

    for i in range( 0, 4 ):
        self . guiElements[ 'Scale' + str( i ) ] = Scale( 
            self . guiElements[ 'LabelFrame4' ],
            variable = self . scaleText[ i ] )

    self . guiElements[ 'Scale0' ] . grid( row = 0, column = 0 )
    self . guiElements[ 'Scale1' ] . grid( row = 0, column = 1 )
    self . guiElements[ 'Scale2' ] . grid( row = 1, column = 0 )
    self . guiElements[ 'Scale3' ] . grid( row = 1, column = 1 )

    self . createBack( self . guiElements[ 'LabelFrame4' ], 2 )
    #Set Up frame4 Gui 
    self . openFrame( 4, 1 )
```

**UPDATE**

This is how i create scaleText variable:

```
self . scaleText = self . appendValue( 4, DoubleVar( ) )

def appendValue( self, bound, value ):
    emptyList = [ ]
    for i in range( 0, bound ):
        emptyList . append( value )
    return emptyList
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete (complete) example exhibiting your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential part which is missing in the code you've shown is where you create all the variables (`self.scaleText[i]`). My guess is that you end up assigning the same variable to all the `scaleText[i]`'s.

**EDIT** You do use the same control variable for all widgets.
Here:

```
self . scaleText = self . appendValue( 4, DoubleVar( ) )
```

you create a `DoubleVar` object and pass it to the `appendValue()` function, which stores 4 copies of it in a list. So your widgets share the same control variable and thus move in unison.

This effect may seem counterintuitive to people unfamiliar with Python/Tkinter, so here is a very brief explanation:

- In Python, objects are passed by reference, so when assigning an object to a variable (or passing it to a function), you just create a new reference to an existing object.
- Changing a `Tkinter` variable causes any widget(s) associated with it (if any) to change their current state accordingly. (In fact, there's a generic [mechanism](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) that allows to receive notifications when TCL/Tk variables are accessed).